# Using BIDS Helper to set parametrized connection parameters

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm trying to use BIDS Helper to change $Package to $Project parameters on connection managers in a bunch of packages. They all have connections with the same name. Here's what one of them looks like:

```
<DTS:ConnectionManager
  DTS:refId="Package.ConnectionManagers[RS]"
  DTS:CreationName="OLEDB"
  DTS:DTSID="{DCA22683-753E-4CEC-B706-169A0BDB754C}"
  DTS:ObjectName="RS">
  <DTS:PropertyExpression
    DTS:Name="InitialCatalog">@[$Package::RS_InitialCatalog]</DTS:PropertyExpression>
  <DTS:PropertyExpression
    DTS:Name="Password">@[$Package::RS_Password]</DTS:PropertyExpression>
  <DTS:PropertyExpression
    DTS:Name="ServerName">@[$Package::RS_ServerName]</DTS:PropertyExpression>
  <DTS:PropertyExpression
    DTS:Name="UserName">@[$Package::RS_UserName]</DTS:PropertyExpression>
```

I tried using "Package.ConnectionManagers[RS].PropertyExpression[InitialCatalog]" and also "\Package.Connections[RS].Parameters[InitialCatalog]" for the Property Path and "$Project::RS_InitialCatalog" for the New Value. It pretends to work, opens each of the selected packages and flashes an hourglass, but the parameter is not changed.

The first path is just guess work on my part and the second is something I found on the net. Both are accepted by the Batch Property Update but have no effect.

Comment: Do you know that Connection Managers, project and package, are special entities you can configure natively in the Integration Services catalog? No need for creating these variables and then assigning them as expressions. It's all straight out of the box capabilities

Comment: The existing project has about 80 packages, each with 3 connection defined in package parameters. Is there an easier way to change them all?

Comment: Also, the project is run with different connections using DTSExec and the connection parameters are specified in config files.

Comment: You're using config files with the project deployment model?

Comment: The project is run against 236 sites and the config files are used to set the parameters. Is there something I am not grocking? This isn't a new project, I'm working with what I have, btw.

Comment: It just hit me... I kept referring to command files but calling them config files. Senior moment, sorry.